# Flask - Requisição POST para mês específico

Tags: python, datetime, lógica, flask

Fala galera, tudo certo?

Sou novo no mundo de programação e estou fazendo meu primeiro projeto que consiste em uma API de orçamentos. No sistema tem o cadastro de uma despesa, onde é passado a data (estou usando datetime) de quando a despesa ocorreu. O meu objetivo é que, quando eu faça uma requisição com o método POST, retorne apenas as despesas do mês que foi passado na requisição (Ex: http://localhost/api/despesas/3, retornar apenas as despesas do mês 3 (março)); sei que devo inserir essa notação no `@app.route('/<int:mes>')` mas não sei como fazer a lógica para pegar apenas o mês da data completa.

Obrigado

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Basta usar o membro month da data.

```
import datetime

date = datetime.date(2023, 3, 1)
month_number = date.month
print(month_number)
```